# Cannot create spreadsheet

Tags: android, google-sheets, gdata

Here is my code:

```
SpreadsheetService spreadsheet= new SpreadsheetService("v1");
    spreadsheet.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);

    try {
        spreadsheet.setUserCredentials("username", "password");
        URL metafeedUrl = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = spreadsheet.getFeed(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);

        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
        for (SpreadsheetEntry service : spreadsheets) {             
            System.out.println(service.getTitle().getPlainText());
       }
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It always crashes in the Constructor for the Spreadsheet. I am using these libraries:

- gdata-client-1.0
- gdata-client-meta-1.0
- gdata-core-1.0
- gdata-spreadsheet-3.0
- gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0
- guava-13.0.1

Can anyone tell me what could be possibly be wrong?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes in the constructor for Spreadsheet? Not SpreadsheetService? Where is an instance of Spreadsheet created? Maybe somewhere behind the scenes, I guess. Anyway, as one commenter said, check with logcat. If you have absolutely no clue where it's crashing (it should tell you, if you read the wall of text that comes up), just throw logcat absolutely everywhere possible.

```
static final String MESSAGE = "SPREADSHEET TEST MESSAGE:";
SpreadsheetService spreadsheet= new SpreadsheetService("v1");
Log.d(MESSAGE, "spreadsheet was created successfully.");
spreadsheet.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);
Log.d(MESSAGE, "setProtocolVersion done successfully.");

try {
    spreadsheet.setUserCredentials("username", "password");
    Log.d(MESSAGE, "set credentials worked.");
    URL metafeedUrl = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
    Log.d(MESSAGE, "metafeedUrl was created successfully.");
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = spreadsheet.getFeed(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    Log.d(MESSAGE, "feed was created, too.");
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
    Log.d(MESSAGE, "spreadsheets List was created successfully.");
    for (SpreadsheetEntry service : spreadsheets) {             
        System.out.println(service.getTitle().getPlainText());
   }
   Log.d(MESSAGE, "The for-loop worked.");
} catch (AuthenticationException e) {           
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It looks stupid, but you can just delete all the messages once it's working. I usually only do this kind of thing if I have no clue in the name of all that is holy what's going on; it should yield more results than just staring at the screen.

Anyway, see where it fails and figure it out from there. Maybe ask a clearer question once you're better informed.

Comment: I am sorry it was suppossed be SpreadsheetService not Spreadsheet. I have used logs and I am completely sure it crashes with SpreadsheetService constructor.I am adding logcat output: